# Recursively add sequence of numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, sequence, addition

Hey im trying to refresh my mind with a bit of recursion.
I want to add all numbers from 'start' to 'end' inclusive.

I.e if start was 1, and end was 5. Then the answer would be 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

So far I've got this

```
int calc(int start, int end){
    if(start > end)
        return total;
    else{
        total = total + start;  
    return sum1(start++, end);
    }
}
```

Its not working (i get seg fault). What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Sorry i am using the same variables in my actual code, when i wrote this i ended up reffering to them as start/end and forgot to change all the code.

Comment: Never use increment operators when a `start+1` would work just as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What are `from` and `to` variables inside your function? Maybe you use some globals instead of using `start` and `end` and that's why you have the problem? Also why are you using `sum1` inside the `calc` function instead of `calc`?

Try this instead:

```
int calc(int start, int end){
    if(start > end)
        return 0;
    else
        return start + calc(start + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
You first answer that has (start++,end) in it caused a segmentation fault, but start + 1 worked. why is this?

Comment: it should have been ++start. pre-increment and not post-increment. start++ will never increment the value passed in to the recursive function and results in infinite loop. Hence segmentation fault.

Comment: @Splendor, @Sean Arnold, `++start` won't cause the segfault, but it can lead to incorrect results since the compiler is free to evaluate the `++start` before or after the `start` earlier in the statement. As a rule, one shouldn't both change and use a variable in an expression.

Comment: @ikegami, start++ (post increment) will cause STACK OVERFLOW EXCEPTION. I tried on my machine. Value passed in is never incremented and remains same. This results in infinite recursive calls. You can run with start++ and verify.

Comment: @Splendor, I know. I never said `start++` is correct. I said `++start` is wrong. You said `start++` is wrong. Both are true.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you aren't using your function parameters (start, end), you are using (from, to) instead.  I assume from and to are either global variables or your code wouldn't compile.  Furthermore, where is total declared?

This should work better:

```
int calc(int start, int end){
    if(start > end)
        return 0;
    else{
        return start + calc(start+1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `++start` in your recursive call.

Comment: Should be `start+1`, actually. `start++` is wrong cause it could be evaluated before the `start + ` earlier in the statement.

Comment: Oh you guys are right, I thought that looked funny I should have changed it.

Answer (score 3):

By the way, here's a more efficient solution:

```
int calc(int from, int to)
{
    if (from == 0)
        return to * (to+1) / 2;
    else
        return calc(0, to) - calc(0, from);
}
```

It's even recursive! Well, until you simplify it further to

```
int calc(int from, int to)
{
    return ( to * (to+1) - from * (from+1) ) / 2;
}
```

That's because f(n) = n+...+3+2+1 = n(n+1)/2

Comment: I think the best solution for this problem is put forth by ikegami.
Sometimes you do not have to take the problems as they are and think of different ways to compute the same thing. What ikegami has shown is a simple implementation of the algorithm for sum of a series to a certain number. It works quite efficiently as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for.

```
int calc(int from, int to)
{
    if (from >= to) return to;
    return from + calc(from + 1, to); 
}
```

Comment: `from++` is wrong cause it could be evaluated before the `from` earlier in the statement. It should be `from + 1`.

Comment: it is not from++ but ++from. (pre-increment)

Comment: same applies to `++from`. `++from` is wrong cause it could be evaluated before or after the `from` earlier in the statement. As a rule, one shouldn't both change and use a variable in an expression.

Comment: @ikegami, I agree +1 for your comments. I have corrected my code. Thank you.